# AWS - How can I receive an SNS alert when a new EC2 Security Group is created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to receive an update when a new EC2 security group is created. Haven't had much luck. There have been a lot of resources online however they don't deal with what I'm trying to do. All I need is an SNS notification when a new security group is created for some reason this is proving harder than it should.

Any suggestions on how I may be able to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three are two services of interest:

- **Amazon CloudWatch Events** can use *rules* to trigger an action when something happens (eg a Security Group is created)
- **Amazon Config** keeps track of historical configurations

For your use-case, I would recommend an **Amazon CloudWatch Events Rule**:

- **Service Name:** EC2
- **Event Type:** AWS API Call via CloudTrail
- **Specific Operation:** CreateSecurityGroup
- **Add Target:** Specify an SNS Topic to receive the notification

Answer (score 3):

The [AWS Config service](https://console.aws.amazon.com/config/home) should serve this purpose perfectly.

It allows you to 'listen' for changes on certain (or all) types of resources and perform certain actions in response.

In your situation you could set up listeners for EC2:SecurityGroup events and have these events trigger notifications being sent to an SNS endpoint of your choice.

See some of the docs on streaming AWS Config events to SNS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/notifications-for-AWS-Config.html).

Comment: Right how exactly do I set up listeners as the issue I have is it asks me to input a lambda function. If I make a lambda function what do I need to put in that function to be able to listen for the events

Comment: @MuhammadHussainMughal You can use any endpoint pointing to SNS, this can be email for example as well, not just a lambda function.